# Using PureMVC framework in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, puremvc

Have been trying to integrate PureMVC framework into an Angular 2 project.
I've manage to build and serve the application but the browser complains about it.

```
import Facade = puremvc.Facade;
import IFacade = puremvc.IFacade;
export class ApplicationFacade extends Facade implements IFacade {
[...]
```

The above snippet compiles just fine but when loading the page I get this error:

```
application-facade.ts:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: puremvc is not defined
at Object.../../../../../src/app/mvc/application-facade.ts (application-facade.ts:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e92bec3fa62ce2032c3:54)
at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.component.ts (app-routing.module.ts:20)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e92bec3fa62ce2032c3:54)
at Object.../../../../../src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts (app.component.ngfactory.ts:34)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e92bec3fa62ce2032c3:54)
at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (environment.ts:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e92bec3fa62ce2032c3:54)
at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:34749)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1e92bec3fa62ce2032c3:54)
```

[PureMVC Standard Framework for TypeScript](https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-typescript-standard-framework)

Anyone with experience regarding this specific integration?